# Bill Of Materials - Breakdown Codes

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Bill of Material Table:

```
Parent    Child
A001      A002
A002      A003
A002      M002
A002      M003
A003      M004
A004      M005
```

What I need to do is return every ACode in the parent column with any MCode further down the line. So the above would return:

```
A001 M002
A001 M003
A001 M004
A002 M002
A002 M003
A002 M004
A003 M004
A004 M005
```

So in short each ACode has every single MCode that goes into it at whatever level it is below.

If you need any more data or information please do not hesitate to ask.

Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing about your task is that the number of levels from an A*** parent to an M*** child can vary. Moreover upfront it isn't clear how many M***s will belong to an A***.

Based on this observation I guess a recursive VBA function would make more sense than Vlookup or Index/Match:

```
Sub Test(needle As String)

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = GetMs(Selection, needle)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Debug.Print needle & "->" & c.Item(i)
    Next i

End Sub


Function GetMs(r As Range, needle As String) As Collection
    Dim c As New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        If r.Cells(i, 1).Value = needle Then
            If Left(r.Cells(i, 2).Value, 1) = "M" Then
                c.Add r.Cells(i, 2).Value
            Else
                Dim tempC As Collection
                Set tempC = GetMs(r, r.Cells(i, 2).Value)
                For j = 1 To tempC.Count
                    c.Add tempC.Item(j)
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Set GetMs = c
End Function
```

This code works if you test it with one A element, e.g.

```
 Test "A001"
```

will print

*A001->M004*

*A001->M002*

*A001->M003*

but make sure that your data range with all parent and child data is selected. Otherwise "Selection" in the Test sub will not work.

From here on you will just need to write your own loop which calls the GetMs function and to handle the result better than just printing it like this test sub here does.

Please note: The code was not optimized for performance.

Cheers

Jens

Comment: It may not be optimised for performance but it works like a dream :)  Appreciated.